# How can I change the button name?(Javascript)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

(This article was written using Google Translate.)

This is App.js.

```
import React,{useState} from 'react';
import Counter from './components/Counter'

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Code</h1>
      <Counter />
      <Counter />
      <Counter />
    </div>
  );
}
export default App;
```

This is Counter.js

```
import React, {useState} from 'react'

const Counter = () => {
    const [count, setCount] = useState(0)
  
  const increment = () => {
    setCount(count + 1)
  }
  return (
      <button onClick={increment}>
        Click {count}
        </button>
  );
}

export default Counter;
```

This is a chrome screen.
Each number is incremented by 1 when the button is pressed.
[image]

But that's not what's important.

I want the first button to be named 'click a'.
And I want to name the second button 'click b'.
And I want to name the third button 'click c'.

I'm learning react for the first time today, so I'm still bad at it.
I'd appreciate it if you could tell me how.

Comment: You want to know how to change, for example, the first button's text from "Click 1" to "Click a" ?

Comment: If you change the captions of the buttons how should they update when they are clicked?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to set a,b,c or any other name to your button name use props to pass the value you want to your button

```
import React, {useState} from 'react'

const Counter = (props) => {
    const { buttonTitle } = props;
    const [count, setCount] = useState(0)
  
  const increment = () => {
    setCount(count + 1)
  }
  return (
     <>
      <h2>{count}</h2>
      <button onClick={increment}>
        Click {buttonTitle}
        </button>
     </>
  );
}
export default Counter;
```

and

```
import React,{useState} from 'react';
import Counter from './components/Counter'

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Code</h1>
      <Counter buttonTitle="a" />
      <Counter buttonTitle="b" />
      <Counter buttonTitle="c" />
    </div>
  );
}
export default App;
```

Comment: You are performing array destructuring on props instead of object destructuring.

Comment: you are right im gonna fix it

Comment: const {name}=props or const Counter = ({name}) => {  }

Answer (score 1):

In your `Counter` component you can accept props from `App` Component

```js
import React, {useState} from 'react'

const Counter = (props) => {
    const [count, setCount] = useState(0)
  
  const increment = () => {
    setCount(count + 1)
  }
  return (
      <button onClick={increment}>
        Click {props.name}
        </button>
  );
}

export default Counter;
```

From your `App` component you can pass down name prop to `Counter` Component

```js
import React,{useState} from 'react';
import Counter from './components/Counter'

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Code</h1>
      <Counter name="a" />
      <Counter name="b" />
      <Counter name="c" />
    </div>
  );
}
export default App;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import React,{useState} from 'react';
import Counter from './components/Counter'

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Code</h1>
      <Counter name='a'/>
      <Counter name='b'/>
      <Counter name='c'/>
    </div>
  );
}
export default App;

//counter.js
import React, {useState} from 'react'

const Counter = (props) => {
    const [count, setCount] = useState(0)
  
  const increment = () => {
    setCount(count + 1)
  }
  return (
    <>  <button onClick={increment}>
        Click {props.name}
        </button>
<p>{count}<p/> </>
  );
}

export default Counter;
```

Comment: Won't this result in error in App component stating a, b & c are not defined ?

Comment: what do you mean not defined?!! these are the values of prop name which passed to counter component

Comment: earlier he was passing as `<Counter name={a} />`

Comment: @MandanaMS They fixed it in an edit. See the [edit history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73156650/revisions) of the post.

Comment: You should, by description, _explain what you've done_. Just dumping a load of code as an answer isn't great.

Comment: Yes I realized now what happed earlier , that was a good point Pratik

Comment: The `Counter` component will throw _"JSX expressions must have one parent element."_ Wrapping the return value with a fragment should be enough though.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should try like this
`Click {String.fromCharCode(count+97)}`

String.fromCharCode(number) it converts number to character & +97 because small alphabets in ASCII starts from 97, for reference check ASCII table.
I hope you wanted this answer.

Comment: It's unclear what the OP is asking for. Either your answer is correct, or everybody else's, depending on what the OP wants.